# close Navigation Drawer with no animation

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to close my navigation drawer after I finish certain activities immediately, without the sliding animation. I don't close it on activity start because I would like it to stay open if the user backs out of the activity. However, I cannot get it to close without a brief flickering animation as it closes itself. I have tried variations of the following code:

```
protected void closeDrawerImmediate() {
    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    mDrawerLayout.setX(0);
    mDrawerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you close it onPause()

Answer (score 7):

You can use the new `DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(int/View, bool)` methods in v24 of the support library to instantly close a drawer:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT, false);
```

If you just want to close a drawer immediately, such as when you're launching an activity from tapping on a drawer item, that is probably enough.

If you want to close the drawer on coming back to the activity, I'd set a stateful boolean like `closeDrawerOnResume = true` wherever is appropriate (eg. starting a new activity), and then in `onResume` check this boolean and close the drawer without animating if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider setting animation time to 0. But it seems it's not as easy as setting one property. Here is [tutorial](http://levibostian.com/android-navigation-drawer-animation-duration/) and the [code](https://gist.github.com/levibostian/94fc1b036670c9532317) but it requires importing sources for `DrawerLayout` and `ViewDragHelper` into project and small modifications there.