# Change transition of Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, navigation-drawer, android-transitions

I want to open navigation drawer with fade in and fade out transition ,
I tried most of things but not success,so please help me to archive this kind of transition effect on navigation drawer.

I have this type of code.

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                drawer.closeDrawers();

//                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(drawer, fadeOut);

            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

//                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(drawer, fadeIn);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what effect you're trying to achieve. Do you want the drawer to fade in based on how far open it is? Or just a timed fade, in place? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the fade in / out animations by creating the following animation xml:

```
<!-- fade out-->    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
        <alpha
            android:duration="2000"
            android:fromAlpha="1.0"
            android:toAlpha="0.1" >
        </alpha>
    </set>
```

r

```
<!--fade in-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

then override the  `onDrawerSlide` of [DrawerLayout.DrawerListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.DrawerListener.html#onDrawerSlide(android.view.View,%20float)), to add the appropriate animation to your drawer menu as it slides open/close. For example:

```
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
                new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                        // Respond when the drawer's position changes
                        Animation animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
                        drawerView.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        // Respond when the drawer is opened
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        // Respond when the drawer is closed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                        // Respond when the drawer motion state changes
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: it worked thanks but i want to remove slide animation too.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38065786/10300673
it explains how to close the drawer without animation. you can do the same with open.

Comment: i try that but drawer closed by slide animation

Comment: please tell me how can i close drawer with fade out animation

Comment: do you want to drag the drawer and fade out as it closes or just click on the drawer button and have it fade out without moving towards the side of the screen?

Comment: no i dont want to drag i want close as fade out on button click

Comment: follow the tutorial on the developers website to add your home nav button here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#ActionBarIcon then inside the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)  , look further down that page, add the fade animations when you click on that button. Set a boolean flag to differentiate between clicking the button to open the menu with fade in effect and clicking the button to close the menu with fade out effect